# Facing Bootstrap Icons alignment issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am using bootstrap navbar, it has brand name on left and 2 icons glyphicon glyphicon-user and glyphicon glyphicon-bell on right.

When i am changing the resolution to less than 768, the brand name and both the icons are getting vertically aligned and height of navbar increases.

[image: The problem]

I do no want a collapse bar. and i want the icons to be fixed at right.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ilu0B.png

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai : here is the jumbled code.

Comment: http://codepen.io/b0y/pen/pgNKvx

Answer (score 2):

Use `pull-left` and `pull-right` with **2** `navbar-header` div's, since they do not attached to any `@media` queries.

**Try this**

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="navbar-header pull-left">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
</div>
<div class="navbar-header pull-right">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></span></button>
</div>
```

[**Working Codepen**](http://codepen.io/liorgrs/pen/wMoXMy?editors=110)

Comment: Hello guy, everything is okay but i do not want the buttons. Also i wanna align them vertically middle on right.

Comment: i can add HTML CSS and JS, can't add Glyphicon font on any of these sites :(

Answer (score 2):

`@Lior G` is right, you can use default `bootstrap` styles (classes) to resolve your issue!

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header pull-left">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav mobileNav pull-right">
      <li class="pull-left">
        <a href="#about"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:26px; color:white"></span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="pull-left">
        <a href="#" class="disabled"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:26px; color:white"></i></a>
      </li>
    </ul> 
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

[jsfiddle-link](https://jsfiddle.net/h8mvuccp/1/)